# Why do some mac encrypted files crash ALL my windows apps?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, crash

Occasionally I get these 'evil files'.

Attempting to open or otherwise interact with them (right click to rename for example) will crash whatever application I am using.

Try to add as attachment in Outlook? Crash.  Try to delete in Win Explorer? Crash.  And so on.

They are always with green file names and appear to be created on a Mac because they have the _macosx folder alongside them.

[image]

I have seen other people have issues with these files (e.g. here and here), but never quite the same issue I have.  The [normal recommendation](http://www.andyrathbone.com/2012/01/30/why-does-windows-show-my-file-names-in-green-letters/) is to uncheck the Encrypt Contents To Secure Data box in properties.  But I can't do this because right clicking in Explorer crashes it.

The only way I have found to delete these files is to start Windows in safe mode.

What might be causing this and what can I do about it?

Comment: Can you upload part of such an 'evil' file so we can take a look at it ?

Comment: I suspect system file corruption.  I don't have this problem.  Most of the software I use are cross-platform with OS X.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a commercially sensitive document so I'm reluctant to upload it somewhere public.  I've been looking to see if I could hunt out any traces of old 'evil files' but I can't find any.  Perhaps I'd better repost this question when I have an example I can upload :(

Comment: FWIW....  one such file originated as a zipped email attachment.  I had saved, unzipped and used the file a number of times over a period of months before it went over to the dark side and had to be deleted.  I went back to my emails to find the file and upload it for this post.  But when I try to unzip, explorer crashes.  It's almost as if it had an expiry date or something. {confused}

Comment: Have you tried them on a new Windows system (possibly a VM)? If you have a shell extension that looks at the file and crashes, that would cause this symptom. It might also be possible to use Safe Mode to change the tickbox.

Comment: I can delete in safe mode, so yes I can try that to change the tickbox. Good thinking, thanks